# Native Google Play Game Services with Apache Cordova?

Tags: cordova, google-play-games

Is it possible to access the native Google Play Games Services through Apache Cordova or an official plugin?

Or will I have to use the Web version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I develop a simple one here: https://github.com/ptgamr/cordova-google-play-game
How it works: http://trinhtrunganh.com/cordova-plugin-for-google-play-game-service/

Answer (score 0):

Here's a plugin, but still alpha. Author says it will finish it soon.

https://github.com/aogilvie/phonegap-plugin-googleGameServices

Answer (score 0):

Another option, apparently more maintained, seems to be this one: https://github.com/cranberrygame/cordova-plugin-game